# Changing what the text to speech engine says when it encounters a word

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I've just started using the Android text to speech engine, in an app I'm writing. It seems great.

However there are some things it says "wrongly", in my context at least. For example when it encounters "&" it says "ampersand" and I want it to say "and". Another example (and probably not what you think), when it encounters "FA" is says something that sounds like "far", I want it to say it as letters, sounding like "eff ay".

Can I do something to influence it in the directions I want?

Whilst this is currently an Android situation for me, I wouldn't be surprised if it becomes an "Apple" one as well.

Answer (score 1):

In regard of the ampersand you could simply replace it with the word 'and' before you pass the text on for processing.
For FA, as Markers said, you could simply replace it with 'F A' (mind the gap).

Answer (score 0):

An answer I've found to the problem of making the text-to-speech engine pronounce groups of letters as individual letters rather than trying to make up a word is to separate them into individual letters by putting spaces between them.

So for example "EX" should (for my purpose) be pronounced "Ee ex", but the engine says "ex" (understandably in the general context), so I simply change the text to "E X" and it comes out the way I want.

Hardly rocket science I know, but it works.  I was hoping to be able to add some markup, as is present in STML (Spoken Text Markup Language), but Google haven't implemented anything like that yet.